# Complex Index and Match

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, match, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to do an advanced Index and Match to return the Hourly OT Rate into cell Y19. I need the formula to first evaluate the level and shift from columns T and W, then match those with intersecting value in the vertical range of E3:E6 (Level) and M2:O2 (OT Rates - Hourly). Based on my limited knowledge of this formula combo, I believe the index here would be M3:O6 since those are the values I'm ultimately looking to return. I'm just not sure how to do so while factoring in the values in T and W.

Sample sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jBDHT445W07lwFQmqrh4Rhk2Tl-RPXMa2xyZiC3JPkY/edit#gid=0

Thanks in advance!

Matt

Answer (score 1):

Try [`filter()`](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197):

```
=filter( filter(M3:O6, M2:O2 = W19), E3:E6 = T19 )
```